# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 22, in <module>
    i.string.replace_with(i.string.replace(u'\xa0', '-'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'
```

Some of the code

```
soup = bs4(open("test.html")) 

table = soup.find("table", {"color":"#fff"})

for i in soup.find_all('small'):
    i.string.replace_with(i.string.replace(u'\xa0', '-'))  <--Line 22
```

It was working yesterday, but I had to reinstall Mint on another VM and I can't get that to work again. How can I fix that?

EDIT: This is all the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

soup = bs4(open("test.html")) 

table = soup.find("table", {"color":"#fff"})

for i in soup.find_all('small'):
    i.string.replace_with(i.string.replace(u'\xa0', '-'))

#print soup
f = open("new.html", "w")
f.write(str(table))
```

This is the table in test.html:

```
<table color="#fff">
<tr>
<td><small><small>&nbsp;</small></small></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: post more of you code. What is `i`?

Comment: @stalk added some of the code. I am reading in a html file

Comment: Is it `replace_with()` or `replace_width()`? You're using both in your question. Could it be a typo in your code?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sorry I mistyped that. It is replace_with

Comment: Clearly `i.string` is `None`. Why do you believe that `i.string` should be other than `None`? Do you understand the error message?

Comment: this looks weird. `find_all` should never return a list containing a `None`. are you sure this is the code raising the exception?

Comment: @WeaselFox I have added the code that I use

Comment: The problem is with `<small><small>&nbsp;</small></small>`. The first `<small>` contains another tag. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string), the `.string` attribute can return `None` if a tag *"contains more than one thing"*.

This only means that one of the elements in you list (`soup.find_all('small')`) is a non-leaf element. For instance :

```
<small>Hello <em>Bobby</em></small>
```

For such an element, `.string` returns `None` because it contains an other element, and the behavior is not defined.

Your code doesn't work because you can't run `None.replace(u'\xa0', '-')`.
 What you need to do is, inside your loop, test whether the iterated element has a defined `.string` member or not.

---

```
for i in soup.find_all('small'):
    if i.string :
        i.string.replace_with(i.string.replace(u'\xa0', '-'))
```

NB : this is a dirty workaround, it won't work if you have

`<small>&nbsp <tag>something unrelated</tag></small>`

Comment: I'm not sure come it was working yesterday (and for weeks before that), but when I tried it today with the same code it doesn't?

Comment: @tonyt - probably the site/your file has changed something in its structure.

Comment: It seems to me that if your script worked for a while, the page you are parsing must have changed in a way it created the undefined behavior that is currently discussed. **You can't be too careful while analyzing some input.**

Comment: @WeaselFox My thought exactly. The `<small><small>&nbsp;</small></small>` mentioned in the OP could only break the whole thing.

Comment: How would I fix that? I would still need change the `&nbsp;` to `-`.  I'm not too sure.

Comment: @tonyt This could be fairly trivial depending on what you are trying to achieve. The question is : *what do you want to do when a `<small>` tag contains another tag ?*

Comment: To see if it contains &nbsp and if so replace it with -

Comment: Added a nice workaround in my answer above. It should work, tell me if otherwise. :)

Comment: Should be okay now. Not a great solution though.